# How to translate a button from its relative position to the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android

I would like to translate a button from its relative position to the bottom of the screen.

I am doing the TranslateAnimation using Java code.

The following is the code snippet of what I've already did:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int screenHeight = display.getHeight();
translateButtonAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, height);
```

The result is that the button fly outside of the emulator screen!! :(

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
Animation toBottom =
    new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, x, 
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f, 
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
toBottom.setDuration(350);
toBottom.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
```

to make sure it gets to the end of your screen. 
`x` and `y` denote the current position of your `Button`.

Comment: Then please provide your source layout with the exact translation description you desire, and don't let us guess what you might already have, and be up to (since this code, and @Kevin's as well are functional in a simple `RelativeLayout`). thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid the button traslation out of the screen in this way(peseudo code):

```
traslation= screenheight-(actualButtonposition.y)

translateButtonAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, height);
```